# Access static variable in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have  class sheldon

```
Class sheldon
{
  public static $text = 1
}
```

In smarty I am trying to access this variable like

```
~$sheldon::$text`
```

but its not working and it giving me the error "syntax error: unrecognized tag: "

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: public static $text = 1; in your class. There is a dollar sign needed.

Comment: updated but why how to access in smarty ?

Comment: Show your actual smarty code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{assign var=foo value=sheldon::$text}
{$foo}
```